# get the nearest date mysql

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have the following dates in my table. How do I find a closest date from either today (if today's date is there) or if today's date is not there then the nearest past date?

```
2012-10-01          aa123
2012-10-02          aa43
2012-10-03          aa478
2012-10-04          aa40    
2012-10-05          aa54
2012-10-06          de34
2012-10-07          a5434
2012-10-08          r4t
2012-10-09          x34
2012-10-10          q23
2012-10-11          b53
```

So if today is `'2012-10-07'` is then the record will be `a5434`. But if `2012-10-07` is missing then the record will be `de34` which belongs to `2012-10-06` since that would be the closest past day from today.

I am not sure where to start on this one, so I haven't tried anything yet. Need a sql solution to this.

Comment: "so I havent tried anything yet" - really?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean when the record is missing - will the date still exist for "missing" records?  Or will the whole row be missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's simple, just get one of the last date <= the current date:

```
$now = date("Y-m-d");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM date_table where date_field <= '$now' ORDER BY date_field DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1";
```

Comment: I think you want to select the `date_data`, not the `date_field`.  Also, this will only work if the whole row is missing when the record is not there - e.g. if the `date_field` is populated, but the `date_data` is blank, then this will fail.

Answer (score 2):

Add an `ORDER BY` statement to the query. The following will order the rows by their date, with the latest at the top and oldest at the bottom.

```
SELECT `id`, `date` FROM `table` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1;
```